# Can I maintain my ethereum wallet on AWS?

Tags: wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Can i download and sync my wallet on Amazon Web Services? Is there any security concern when using Cloud services assuming that all the cloud based servers are encrypted.

Comment: Can you explain the process that you were thinking of using? Storing the downloaded block-chain, or the JSON file that includes the encrypted private key?

Comment: @xgabrielx to store the blockchain for syncing my wallet

Comment: I don't see the point of doing it, but you don't need to consider security since "the blockchain" is public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how much you trust them to keep your keys safe. People will give you their opinion as to how safe they think AWS is, but at the end of the day you need to be comfortable in your understanding of what you think your threat model is in using their services.

---

It doesn't directly answer your question, but a few further things you'd need to consider as well as security:

- Cost
- Service uptime
- Data integrity

---

**Cost**

You'll be downloading a lot of data and potentially using a fair amount of bandwidth to keep you wallet up to date.

**Service uptime**

[Their SLA](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/sla/) (Service Level Agreement) doesn't explicitly guarantee uptime. You can hunt around the internet for ideas of what their uptime actually is in practice, but from what I've seen in the past it's not quite "[5 9s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_nines)". If you want guaranteed access to your wallet at *all times*, you'll need to ensure you've taken a back-up of your keys, and are aware of how to use other wallet services.

**Data integrity**

If you accidentally delete your instances (including your keystore, etc.), and want to recover the data, then you might struggle. Amazon don't publish their data retention policies (which are different to the user-configured back-up retention policies). Their [security whitepaper](http://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/Security/AWS%20Security%20Whitepaper.pdf) would be worth a read.

Of course, the second and third points are mitigated by taking back-ups of your keys.